# Know which table are affected by a connection

Tags: postgresql

I want to know if there is a way to retrieve which table are affected by request made from a connection in PostgreSQL 9.5 or higher.

The purpose is to have the information in such a way that will allow me to know which table where affected, in which order and in what way.

More precisely, something like this will suffice me :

```
id | datetime | id_conn | id_query | table   | action
---+----------+---------+----------+---------+-------
1  | ...      | 2256    | 125      | user    | select
2  | ...      | 2256    | 125      | order   | select
3  | ...      | 2256    | 125      | product | select
```

(this will be the result of a select query from user join order join product).

I know I can retrieve id_conn througth "pg_stat_activity", and I can see if there is a running query, but I can't find an "history" of the query.

The final purpose is to debug the database when incoherent data are inserted into the table (due to a lack of constraint). Knowing which connection do the insert will lead me to find the faulty script (as I have already the script name and the id connection linked).

Comment: Did you consider adding the missing constraint(s)?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Yes, that's one of the purpose of it : detect design flaw and proposing a correction. However, the database is quit huge, so it will be impossible to do a full audit of it, at least it will cost us too great for the benefit (the database is currently "working"). moreover, sometine I have to know how many / which script acces a certain table in order to fix the script itself.

Comment: There is no way to get that information since it isn't tracked. You can get the statements from the log if you set `log_statement = 'all'`.